# Proc throws error when used with do end

Tags: ruby, rack, proc

This doesn't work:

```
run Proc.new do |env|
  [200, 
   {
    "Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  }, ["{\"name\":\"Rack App\"}"]]
end
```

But this does:

```
run Proc.new { |env|
  [200, 
   {
    "Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  }, ["{\"name\":\"Rack App\"}"]]
}
```

Any ideas, why its throwing error when used with do..end?

Error I am getting:

`app.ru:1:in new: tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)`

Comment: `do end` vs `{ }` has different precedence so it may be run something like `run do; # code end; Proc.new` but `{}` may run this as you intended: `proc11 = Proc.new {; # code }; run proc11`. Well, that I think is the problem but I don't know rack too much so, that's why it is a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code is interpreted as:

```
run(Proc.new) do |env|
  ...
end
```

and the block is is passed to `run` instead of `new`. The problem can be solved by doing:

```
run(Proc.new do |env|
  ...
end)
```

Comment: Should be a result of precedence rules? I suppose. Anyways, thanks marking you answer right.

Comment: Yes, it is a result of it.